# How to align a dashrule?

Tags: formatting, rules

I've been playing around with the [**dashrule**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule) package. But easy as it's shown in the manual, I don't get a proper alignment or width from the dashlines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][x]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][c]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the leftmost dash at the left margin and the rightmost dash at the right margin – means: widened gaps – (argument [x])
OR
equal remaining space on the left and right margin (argument [c]). Both should be possible.

Comment: I'm afraid that the package can not handle this.

Comment: You request seems a bit contradictory, or at least unclear: if you want to align the “outermost” dashes to the text margins, simply use the `x` option and the dashes will line up by themselves (since the width of the dashed lines is always the same).  If, on the other hand, you want to draw dashed lines of different width, you cannot have _both_ aligned dashes and no gaps at the ends -- at least, not in general.

Comment: I want to use the x option. Check my MWE. It's not working, see graphic. The rightmost dash doesn't align to the rules=margin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this with leaders, but you can instead make TeX count how many copies of the dash will fit when a minimum gap between them is added and substitute this minimum gap with `\hfill` to cover up your tracks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fillwithdashes}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { musicman/dashes } { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_musicman_dash_box
   {
    \rule[\l_musicman_height_dim]{\l_musicman_width_dim}{\l_musicman_thickness_dim}
   }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_musicman_target_dim { #2 - \box_wd:N \l_musicman_dash_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_musicman_piece_dim
   {
    \box_wd:N \l_musicman_dash_box + \l_musicman_gap_dim
   }
  \leavevmode
  \box_use:N \l_musicman_dash_box
  \prg_replicate:nn
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_musicman_target_dim } { \l_musicman_piece_dim }
   }
   { \hfill \box_use:N \l_musicman_dash_box }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { musicman/dashes }
 {
  thickness .dim_set:N = \l_musicman_thickness_dim,
  height    .dim_set:N = \l_musicman_height_dim,
  width     .dim_set:N = \l_musicman_width_dim,
  min-gap   .dim_set:N = \l_musicman_gap_dim,
  thickness .initial:n = 0.4pt,
  height    .initial:n = 0pt,
  width     .initial:n = 1.5mm,
  min-gap   .initial:n = 1.5mm,
 }
\box_new:N \l_musicman_dash_box
\dim_new:N \l_musicman_target_dim
\dim_new:N \l_musicman_piece_dim

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\hrule height 1pt
\strut\fillwithdashes[height=0.5ex,width=1.5mm,min-gap=1mm,thickness=0.4pt]{\linewidth}
\hrule height 1pt

\bigskip

\hrule height 1pt
\strut\fillwithdashes{\linewidth}
\hrule height 1pt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my edit to my answer (and please confirm that it is now visible to anyone, see my last comment! -- Thanks).  EDIT: For being visible, it is visible :-) .

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes, it's visible and shows that indeed it can be done with `\xleaders`. But I believe that counting an making the gap a bit flexible is better.

Comment: With `\xleaders` the gap _is_ flexible; or better, there is a flexible gap between the repeated boxes that adds up to the “off part” of the dashes.

Comment: Please see edit to my answer: only your answer is correct, mine is not! :-)

Comment: @egreg If I wanted to do the same thing but for dots, shoud I just change,`\rule[\l_musicman_height_dim]{\l_musicman_width_dim}{\l_musicman_thickness_dim}` with `\raisebox{\l_musicman_height_dim}{$\cdot$\kern\l_musicman_width_dim}`?

Comment: @FormlessCloud I'd say `\raisebox{\dim_eval:n{\l_musicman_height_dim-.5\height}}{$\cdot$\kern\l_musicman_width_dim}`

Answer (score 4):

If you pass `x` as the second optional argument to `\hdashrule`, it is converted to the `\xleaders` TeX primitive; with `c`, you get TeX’s `\cleaders`; and with nothing, you get TeX’s `\leaders`, which is what you want.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][x]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][c]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{1.5mm}
\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}

Making it more visible:

\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][x]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{2mm 7mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex][c]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{2mm 7mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{2mm 7mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{2mm 7mm}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}{2mm 7mm}
\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}

\end{document}
```

Oh, and here is the output, too:

[image: Output of the code]

**Addition** (Erroneous, see below)

The OP clarified their question (see comments).  Well, sometimes a little, quick-and-dirty trick is the best solution (or, at least, the easiest one!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\newcommand*{\mydashedrule}[1]{%
  \hdashrule[0.5ex][x]{\dimexpr\linewidth+#1\relax}{0.5pt}{#1}%
  \nobreak\hspace{-#1}\null
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}
\mydashedrule{6mm}
\mydashedrule{6mm}
\mydashedrule{6mm}
\mydashedrule{6mm}
\mydashedrule{6mm}
\rule[0mm]{\linewidth}{1mm}


\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of the quick-and-dirty trick]

**Afterthought**

The above “quick-and-dirty trick” contains a gross mistake, in that (as it is, in a sense, obvious, and as *The TeXbook* explains in detail on page 224, in the paragraph that precede Exercise 21.4, which is also relevant) `\xleaders` leaves some blank space also before the first one, and after the last one, of the repeated boxes.  The amount of this blank space depends on the difference between the space that is to be filled by `\xleaders...\hskip` and the total width occupied by the repeated boxes themselves; this means that, in order to compensate for this amount, you have to measure, in a way or in another, the width of space that the whole construction is supposed to fill up.  In other words, I’d say the only correct answer to this question is egreg’s: this one is not!

Comment: sorry, I think my question was not clear enough, I've updated it

Comment: The OP wants the first dash at the left margin and the last dash at the right margin, with the others evenly spaced in the middle.

Comment: to get the dashes to completely fill the line, it's usually necessary to measure carefully, and make sure that the line length exactly equals the number of dashes plus the number of gaps (which must be the number of dashes minus 1).  i'm sure this can be calculated automatically, but i've always done it by trial and error, starting with a good guess.

Comment: @Sigur: I’m afraid, then, that this is not a task for `\leaders`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's what I think :( I will try it tomorrow with the `calc` package

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- it *is* a task for `\leaders`, but as far as i know, no document class has defined its text width with an eye to it's being a proper multiple of [(dash + space) + dash] so getting the "ideal" alignment will always be a matter of tuning.

Comment: I edited my answer, but I did it without remebering to log in!  Now I have approved my own edit, so it should be visible to anyone.